# SSIS ignoring an Excel column completely

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I am developing a new system to pull down IT ticket reports from an external system, import them periodically to a SQL DB, run calculations on the values and export the results.

I am using SSIS to import the excel reports to the DB. But when I setup my Excel Source, it seems to be ignoring the last column of the worksheet. I can't figure out why. All the datatypes are correct, and the import is working for all the other columns.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How much column you have in that excel?

Comment: Correct worksheet? Correct file?

Comment: did u check the SQl command text in the Excel data_source?

Comment: Does the last column appear in the Advanced Editor for Excel Source, on the Input and Output Properties tab page?

Comment: What's in the last column?

Comment: @BIDeveloper Yes everything is right. It is showing every column except the last one.

Comment: @AbdulRasheed I'm not using any SQL for the excel data. im simply selecting the whole excel sheet.

Comment: @richard345 no it doesn't. there is absolutely no sign of it!

Comment: @TabAlleman the last column contains work notes

Comment: And work notes are what?   Plain text?

Comment: @TabAlleman Yes just a string. I had this working before and was importing perfectly to the DB table as nvarchar(max)

Comment: Issue solved. I had the Excel files on a shared drive within my company and was using the mapped drive address as the filepath, whereas I should have used the full network path.

Answer (score 1):

If you could not find answer quickly, you could force the Excel connection manager to load data from which column to which column, try to locate **open rowset**properties in advanced properties window, for example, Sheet1$A1:Z will writes data to column A to column Z start from row #1 (regardless of the header)